# Can an adjective implement neither attributive, nor preficative role?

Tags: adjectives

> good pants

Is 'good' there an attributive? Is it necessary to be attributive here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. It attributes a property, goodness, to the pants. If the expression were "The pants are good.", that would be a predicate adjective. What other possibility did you have in mind?

Comment: Maybe adjective nonattributive and nonpredicative simulteneously?